# Left/right align buttons and fixed width

Tags: css

So, this is my code.  and I am have problems with it.

1. Solved
2. I want goLeft and goRight to be to the left and right of the Title/descrption.  (Shown in image below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBbV8.png

Any help fixing it would be appreciated!  I was thinking about putting the goleft/goright in a different div, but it didnt work out.

```
jsfiddle.net/ubffv190/
```

Comment: could you please provide jsfiddle code ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ubffv190/

Comment: Go to this site you will get the idea:
https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/cdn7cdj4/

all that was needed to be done is adding

```
display: inline-block
```

to img-wrap class.

The problem was that the entire div was a block filling 100% of the page width, once you define it as an inline-block, it uses only what needed.